# How to horizontally align divs in footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to create a footer component for a custom Wordpress site and am getting a bit stuck on aligning the 3 divs within the footer tag. I'm new to HTML and css and trying to learn and help with this project. Any help that can be given is much appreciated.

```
<body>
<style>
.dust-footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 150;
    height: 150;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    

}
.mix-footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 115;
    height: 100;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: gray;
    

}
.nav-footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:gray;
    color: white;
    
}
</style>

<footer>
<div class="dust-footer">
<h1>DustMasters</h1>
</div>
<div class="mix-footer">
<h1>Mix Section</h1>
</div>
<div class="nav-footer">
<h1>Navigation</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `display: flex` on the footer, and google for the adequate `justify-content` setting.

Comment: Thank you for the assist. I have added a footer display: flex, now for the justify-content do I have to add that to each of the divs that I want to align and are right next to each other?

Comment: @MikeKulas You only apply to the parent, which is `footer`. Check out my answer below

Comment: `justify-content`is applied to the flex *container*, i.e. to the footer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Johannes, `display: flex` would be the best way for horizontal alignment. You can then apply [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#justify-content) accordingly based on your desired effect. More info on flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

There are several other issues in your original code to keep in mind:

- You're missing a closing tag for `<footer>`: `</footer>`
- If you need to offset a certain distance, you need units whenever it's not 0. For instance, `bottom: 150` should be `bottom: 150px` if that's what you meant. Since we're using flexbox, I removed the existing `position: fixed` and offsets applied.

The following code should achieve your desired effect:

```html
<body>
<style>
footer {
    display: flex; /* added style */
    justify-content: space-around; /* added style */
}

.dust-footer {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    

}
.mix-footer {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: gray;
    

}
.nav-footer {
    background-color:gray;
    color: white;
    
}
</style>

<footer>
<div class="dust-footer">
<h1>DustMasters</h1>
</div>
<div class="mix-footer">
<h1>Mix Section</h1>
</div>
<div class="nav-footer">
<h1>Navigation</h1>

</div>

</footer>
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.